# Why does zero raised to any positive power equal zero?

Tags: exponentiation

What if you raised 0 to the power of 2?

Comment: $x^n$ for any $n$ is a polynomial with a unique root at $x=0$ with multiplicity $n$.

Comment: $0^2$ means $0 \times 0$ , and $0$ times anything is $0$.  Likewise $0^3 = 0 \times 0^2$ equals $0$ as well. $\sqrt{0} \times \sqrt{0} = 0$ by definition of square root, so that is $0$ as well.

Comment: $0^2$ would be $0 \times 0$. Which is, of course, equal to $0$. And $0^3 = 0\times 0 \times 0$ and $0^k$ for any positive whole number would be $\underbrace{0\times 0 \times .... \times 0}_{k \text{ times}}$ which are also obviously equal to $0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well for any $x$, $x^2=x\times x$. And so setting $x=0$, $0^2=0\times 0=0$. Alternatively you can generalise this.
$$x^n=x\times x\times \cdots \times x$$
$n$ times. And for any $n>0$. Setting $x=0$ you get $0$ :). I hope this helps.